# external hd formatted for bootcamp setup drive now can't be found

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, boot-camp

I've recently setup bootcamp on my Mac (OSx Mavericks). Using the bootcamp assistant I setup an external HD with the bootcamp files as recommended and have installed IE 8.1 successfully.

I've now been trying to access the external HD to wipe and reuse, but I can't find it either on Windows or OSx. It's not appearing in any of the tools i've tried so far. The drive lights up when plugged in and after a minute or two it goes off.

I'm not sure what to do with this or how to find it - is there a way using terminal to find and reformat it?

Comment: If you can remove the drive, attempt accessing it using a tool such as a Ubuntu Live CD to find the drive and format it.

Comment: it's an external drive, so yeah, can remove it. I've not got ubuntu anywhere to work with, just osx and IE.

Comment: I am supplying this solution as a comment instead of an answer because there's probably another issue here but...go grab a USB thumb drive, put Ubuntu on it. See what happens when you try to mount or partition that drive from within Ubuntu.

Comment: If the filesystem is not corrupt, provided there are no hardware issues, you may be able to mount the drive even, and use the thumb drive as a place to move files out of (if you need to save anything).

Comment: Lack of drive discovery in OSX is usually a hardware issue. Last question: does the disk appear in disk utility?

Comment: Sorry, i'm confused. If i put ubuntu on a thumb drive, how do i connect it to the external hd? or do you mean to test that on the mac? sry for being thick.

Comment: @dmanexe - it's not showing in the disk utility. it was until i used it for the damned bootcamp tool, but not anymore.

Comment: Go run `diskutil list` with the external plugged in and report the result.